# How to write the post's "stars" under separate database, and keep the starCount under the post?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating an android application using firebase as database, and I'm trying to write the stars(which contain the list of users who stared the post to be under separate firebase database, in order to make the database more shallow, and the post's snapshot less expensive.

Currently When the users click the star, first it adds his $uid the stars (or remove it if he already stared the post), then perform a starCount accordingly + or -. Both "stars" and starCount are under the "posts".

I want to have the "stars/postKey/uid" updated under separate database, and keep the starCount under the post.

[please see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fj4SR.jpg)

The codes in the fragment is:

```
    // Bind Post to ViewHolder, setting OnClickListener for the star button
            viewHolder.bindToPost(model, new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View starView) {
                    // Need to write to both places the post is stored
                    DatabaseReference globalPostRef = mDatabase.child("posts").child(postRef.getKey());
                    DatabaseReference userPostRef = mDatabase.child("user-posts").child(model.uid).child(postRef.getKey());


                    // Run two transactions
                    onStarClicked(globalPostRef);
                    onStarClicked(userPostRef);

                }
            });

         }
    };

    mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}//end of onCreateActivity

// [START post_stars_transaction]
private void onStarClicked(DatabaseReference postRef) {
    postRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            Post p = mutableData.getValue(Post.class);
            //Likes l = mutableData.getValue(Likes.class);
            if (p == null) {
                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
            }

            if (p.stars.containsKey(getUid())) {
                // Unstar the post and remove self from stars
                p.starCount = p.starCount - 1;
                p.stars.remove(getUid());
            } else {
                // Star the post and add self to stars
                p.starCount = p.starCount + 1;
                p.stars.put(getUid(), true);
            }

            // Set value and report transaction success
            mutableData.setValue(p);
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                               DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Transaction completed
            Log.d(TAG, "postTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
        }
    });
}
```

I've been trying for a week but didn't succeed, I'm new to programming and very much appreciate your help.

Thanks @Alex for your answer ,  as I wanted to have stars/postKey/uid, I have revised your suggestion and now it works well, but I still have two issues 1) I want to delete the stars node from the post, when I do this, when the user Unstar the post, it looks for $uid under the post ( p.stars), as the stars is part of the Post object, so if stars is empty or does not contain the $uid,  the starCount will not work.  this is my new code,it writes stars to two nodes (starCount is working and connected to stars node, which is under the Post).

```
    private void onStarClicked(final DatabaseReference postRef) {
    postRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            Post p = mutableData.getValue(Post.class);
            //Likes l = mutableData.getValue(Likes.class);
            if (p == null) {
                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
            }

            if (p.stars.containsKey(getUid())) {
                // Unstar the post and remove self from stars
                p.starCount = p.starCount - 1;
                p.stars.remove(getUid());
                DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                DatabaseReference starsRef = rootRef.child("stars");
                starsRef.child(postRef.getKey()).child(getUid()).setValue(null);
            } else {
                // Star the post and add self to stars
                p.starCount = p.starCount + 1;
                p.stars.put(getUid(), true);
                DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                DatabaseReference starsRef = rootRef.child("stars");
                starsRef.child(postRef.getKey()).child(getUid()).setValue(true);
            }

            // Set value and report transaction success
            mutableData.setValue(p);
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                               DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Transaction completed
            Log.d(TAG, "postTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
        }
    });
}
```

The firebasedatbase looks like this

[The firebasedatbase now looks like this, please see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fofS.jpg)

The second issue I have, that the below code to change the stars UI, is also connected to stars node that is under the Post.

```
                    // Determine if the current user has liked this post and set UI accordingly
          //  if (model.stars.containsKey(getUid())) {

            if (model.stars.containsKey(getUid())) {
                viewHolder.starView.setImageResource(com.bl3rbi.firebase.quickstart.bl3rbi.R.drawable.likes_nt_rd);
            } else {
                viewHolder.starView.setImageResource(com.bl3rbi.firebase.quickstart.bl3rbi.R.drawable.likes_nt_w);
            }
            final String postKey2 = getRef(position).getKey();
```

How I can delete the original stars node which is under the Post and connect the starCount and changes of the star UI to the new stars node.

I do really appreciate your support on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a database structure which looks like this:

```
Firebase-root
     |
     --- stars
           |
           --- pushedId1
                  |
                  --- uid1: true
                  |
                  --- uid2: true
```

Please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference starsRef = rootRef.child("stars");
starsRef.push().child(uid).setValue(true);
```

In which the `uid` is the id of the user you want to add into this node.

Comment: Thanks @Alex, I have used your code and done some changes, now it works but I have two issue if I deleted the stars node, under the Post; The starCount doesn't work, and the star UI also doesn't work,as both are connected to the original stars nodeunder the Post, please see above, I added to my original question.

Comment: It's not working because there are different references. You need to change them accordingly. To delete a node, you can simply delete it from the Firebase console. When deleting something, make also a copy before.